# Angular 6 + Electron save images from api for better performance

Tags: angular, api, typescript, electron, angular6

I am making a cryptocurrency portofolio and i am loading the coin data from the cryptocompare api.Is there a way to save the images on local storage?

EDIT: i am using electron

Comment: I don't think you can use localStorage for that (unless you serialise it to base64 first), but maybe have a look at indexedDB

Comment: The browser will do that for you. But you can use `URL.createObjectURL` to create a local resource if you want to.

Comment: Oh i understand.I forgot to mention i was using electron but i found what i was looking for,thanks!